# video-js not work in chrome browser (continuously loading)

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, html5-video

i downloaded video js and changed the source to my local video it works on ie and waterfox but not in chrome it continuously loading.. i used mp4 and ogv as video type i notice this problem    when i go to video js website. the home page video continuously loading without playing it. but it was fine with other browsers how do i fix this

here's my code

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Video.js | HTML5 Video Player</title>

<!-- Chang URLs to wherever Video.js files will be hosted -->
<link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!-- video.js must be in the <head> for older IEs to work. -->
<script src="video.js"></script>

<!-- Unless using the CDN hosted version, update the URL to the Flash SWF -->
<script>
videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
</script>


</head>
<body>
```

```
  data-setup="{}">
<source src="videos/video.mp4" type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' </source>
<source src="videos/video.ogv" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"'></source> 

<track kind="captions" src="demo.captions.vtt" srclang="en" label="English"></track><!-- Tracks need an ending tag thanks to IE9 -->
```